# SQL - group by column 1, order by column 2

Tags: mysql, postgresql

Here's my situation, I have two tables named `people` and `contacts` respectively

```
id name
1  dev one
2  dev two
3  dev three
4  dev five
5  dev four
```

```
id  person_id code_name updated_at
1   1         base1     2019-12-18 00:00:01
2   3         base2     2019-12-18 00:00:02
3   2         home      2019-12-18 00:00:03
4   2         home2     2019-12-18 00:00:04
5   3         work      2019-12-18 00:00:05
6   4         work      2019-12-18 00:00:06
7   5         base      2019-12-18 00:00:07
8   4         base2     2019-12-18 00:00:08
9   2         base      2019-12-18 00:00:09
10  5         work      2019-12-18 00:00:10
```

And I'm trying to get a result from contacts where its ordered by most recent updated_at and grouped(note: not exactly the sql "group by") by person_id, that looks similar to the following result.

```
id  person_id code_name updated_at
10  5         work      2019-12-18 00:00:10
7   5         base      2019-12-18 00:00:07
9   2         base      2019-12-18 00:00:09
4   2         home2     2019-12-18 00:00:04
3   2         home      2019-12-18 00:00:03
8   4         base2     2019-12-18 00:00:08
6   4         work      2019-12-18 00:00:06
5   3         work      2019-12-18 00:00:05
2   3         base2     2019-12-18 00:00:02
1   1         base1     2019-12-18 00:00:01
```

Currently I'm ordering the contacts table by **person_id desc** and **updated_at desc** and results to a bit close of what I expected but not exactly correct.

See results when doing `ORDER BY person_id DESC, updated_at DESC` https://monosnap.com/file/xN0cuZAu2x2df4Q5qNDksKq5P3sEjU contact with `id => 1` should be at the top of the result set since it's the most recent updated of them all.

Note: PostgreSQL is my first use case on this case but it's nice to know also for MySQL if there is any difference.

Comment: But your desired output is not grouped by `person_id`, because then there would be only a single row per group. Do you mean "ordered" rather than "grouped"?

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for `ORDER BY person_id DESC, updated_at DESC` ?

Comment: yes @LaurenzAlbe its not exactly a grouped by person_id, I might misleading the "group by" term here, by "group by" I mean all rows having the same "person_id" should come together in the result

Comment: @RickJames yes that's my current work around but its not exactly correct, for instance row 1 from contacts table gets updated, `ORDER BY person_id DESC, updated_at DESC` will not make it appear at the top of the result set.

Comment: Why not? I think @RickJames is right.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe its because doing so will result into something like 
https://monosnap.com/file/xN0cuZAu2x2df4Q5qNDksKq5P3sEjU
contacts#1 should be at the top

Comment: I think you should add your desired result to the question.

Comment: And decide which RDBMS you're using

Comment: Ok I updated the description

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the following in the `PostgreSQL 9.3`.

Data Sample:

```
create table contact
(
    id int,
    person_id int,
    code_name varchar(20),
    updated_at timestamp
);

INSERT INTO contact VALUES
(1,1,'base1','2019-12-18 00:00:01'),
(2,3,'base2','2019-12-18 00:00:02'),
(3,2,'home','2019-12-18 00:00:03'),
(4,2,'home2','2019-12-18 00:00:04'),
(5,3,'work','2019-12-18 00:00:05'),
(6,4,'work','2019-12-18 00:00:06'),
(7,5,'base','2019-12-18 00:00:07'),
(8,4,'base2','2019-12-18 00:00:08'),
(9,2,'base','2019-12-18 00:00:09'),
(10,5,'work','2019-12-18 00:00:10');
```

Query:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TEMP_Stage_Table;

SELECT  string_agg(id::text,',' order by updated_at desc) id,
    person_id,
    string_agg(code_name,',' order by updated_at desc) code_name,
    string_agg(updated_at::text,',' order by updated_at desc) updated_at INTO TEMP_Stage_Table 
FROM contact
GROUP BY person_id
ORDER BY MAX(updated_at) DESC;

SELECT  regexp_split_to_table(t.id, E',') AS id,
    t.person_id, 
    regexp_split_to_table(t.code_name, E',') AS code_name,
    regexp_split_to_table(t.updated_at, E',') AS updated_at 
FROM TEMP_Stage_Table t;
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

(MySQL/MariaDB syntax)

This will find the "ordering" for each "group of rows" for a person, correct?

```
SELECT MAX(updated_at), person_id
    FROM tbl GROUP BY person_id ;
```

So, let's make use of that thus:

```
SELECT y.*
    FROM (SELECT MAX(updated_at) AS latest, person_id
               FROM tbl GROUP BY person_id ) AS x
    JOIN tbl AS y  USING(person_id)
    ORDER BY x.latest DESC, y.updated_at DESC;
```